# How to raise number through while loop in SwiftUI View

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm SwiftUI Beginner! I'm trying to add Auto Numbering
But, I can't do it..
I don't know how to raise number of variable x

I want to add through while loop or for loop!

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView : View{
   @State var x : Int = 1;
   var body : some View{
     Text(x)
   }
}
```

Comment: Hint: `ForEach`.

Answer (score 0):

As @El Tomato has said you can use `ForEach`. Here's an example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var numberOfRows: Int = 5
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(0..<numberOfRows) {
            Text("\($0)")
        }
    }
}
```